JSON parsing isn't working after enabling Proguard
JSON parsing isn't working after enabling Proguard . I have activity like this
package com.alamart;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tx1;
    private TextView tx2;
    private String json;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> map = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> jumlahBarang = new ArrayList<>();
    private GetSize getSize;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            InputStream is = MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("1.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
            map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>() {
            }.getType());
            for (HashMap<String, Object> item : map) {
                HashMap<String, Object> newItem = new HashMap<>();
                newItem.put("coklat", item.get("coklat"));
                jumlahBarang.add(newItem);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tx1 = findViewById(R.id.tx1);
        tx1.setText(String.valueOf(jumlahBarang.size()));

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }
}

tx1.setText(String.valueOf(jumlahBarang.size()));  

tx1 should display the number 9, but when enabling ProGuard, it displays the number 0 instead.
What puzzles me is that there's no issue on the AVD. tx1 displays the number 9 even with ProGuard enabled. But why does it display the number 0 on the physical Android device?
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


Proguard renames classes, methods, fields and so on, but Gson uses the names for mapping json fields to Java object properties, therefore it is expected that Proguard kills json (de)serialization. You can try to configure Proguard to "keep" certain classes like TypeToken, methods, ... but if course that means they will not be obfuscated...

How do you write it in ProGuard rules?

Have you checked other ProGuard topics like  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49383069/150978?

the case has been completed. Thank you for providing a reference
