Android app crashing in release mode when minifyEnabled = true
I am using minifyEnabled = true and the project works fine in debug mode. But when I generated the release build it crashed on startup. I think it is due to Hilt. Can someone tell me the rules to add in the proguard file?

Please tell me the rules to add in proguard-rules.pro file. Thanks

Please do not post error and stack traces as screenshot, that makes it really hard to read them. Minimizing an app is a lot of work as often the automatic detection if classes are used or not is wrong. So you need to manually configure which classes have to be kept. Especially when libraries for automatic (de)serialization are used such a working configuration can be quite a bit of work to identify which classes and methods to keep.

@Robert How can I keep all Hilt classes?

Have you read other questions and answers on this topic here in SO? Try e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386368/150978

Please also share your current proguard file.

Make sure you mention you models inside the proguard file
